# having trouble in get authentication twitter API with R

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

first of all, i`m not as english speaker. please understand if i make wrong expression.

i`m trying to get authenticate twitter API with using R

i follow the instruction on Internet. but doesn`t work. Error messages keep appear on the screen

```
library(twitteR)

 library(ROAuth)

 library(RCurl)

 library(bitops)

 library(digest)

 library(rjson)

 consumerkey = "mykey"

 consumerSecret = "mysecret"

 requestURL <- "URL"

 authURL = "URL"

 accessURL = "URL"

 twitCred <-OAuthFactory$new(consumerkey=consumerkey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=requestURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)
```

`Error in envRefSetField(.Object, field, classDef, selfEnv, elements[[field]]) : 
  ‘consumerkey’ is not a field in class “OAuth”`

somebody tell my how to figure it out??

Comment: What about `consumerKey` instead of `consumerkey`?

Comment: Note you don't need to load dependencies manually. When you load twitteR that automatically loads RCurl (which in turn loads bitops), rjson, and ROAuth (which in turn loads digest). So just do `library("twitteR")`.